# Собрать свойства класса в коллекцию программно

Tags: c#, list, properties

```
public static List<string> ButtonTitles => new List<string>() {
            AddNewNotifyTitle, BackTitle, FurtherTitle, SaveTitle, DeleteNotifyTitle, MyNotificationsTitle
        };

public static string AddNewNotifyTitle => "Поставить напоминание";
public static string BackTitle => "Назад";
public static string FurtherTitle => "Далее";
public static string SaveTitle => "Сохранить";
public static string DeleteNotifyTitle => "Удалить напоминания";
public static string MyNotificationsTitle => "Мои напоминания";
```

Как инициализацию листа сделать программно, без прописи "ручками" его содержимого?

Comment: System.Reflection смотрели? Type.GetProperties()

Comment: Ваш совет помог, большое спасибо.

Comment: А почему вы используете набор констант вместо, например, словаря? Опишите свою реальную задачу